# Pass the user login email address to next FragmentActivity

Tags: android, authentication, logout

when my LoginAsyncTask calling the ActivityMenu.java i want to send the email address with it as shown in the code. but the value for email is null. I tried both email and Email but still its value is null.

purpose I want to send this is i want to show the logged in user name in the next scree.

```
   public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject> {

    private JSONObject responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;
    private Activity activity;
    String email;

    public LoginAsyncTask(Context context) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
    }

    // async task to accept string array from context array
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        HashMap<String, String> request = null;
        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity requestString = null;
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

        // get the email and password
        Log.i("Email", params[0]);
        Log.i("Password", params[1]);

        try {

            path = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // set the API request
            request = new HashMap<String, String>();
            request.put(new String("Email"), params[0]);
            request.put(new String("Password"), params[1]);
            request.entrySet().iterator();

            // Store locations in JSON
            requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
            requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString()); // requestJson has the email address

            // sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Handles the response
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            responseJson = new JSONObject(response);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String myResJson;
        try {

            myResJson = responseJson.getString("Status");
            String test = myResJson;
            if (test.equals("200")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, ActivityMenu.class);
                intent.putExtra("user", email); // email value is null
                contxt.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(contxt,
                        "Login Error, invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

an help to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email` is `null` because not assigning value which receiving in `doInBackground` . so add

```
email= params[0];
```

in `doInBackground` to get value in `email`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not make an assignment to email.
try:

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
   ...
   ...
   email= params[0];
}
```